# How to Install 10.10 to an External Hard Drive

Tags: 10.10, installation, external-hdd, ppc

I recently got a used external hard drive from a relative, and decided that I would like to have a fresh system around, so I can program, etc. without all of my junk around.  I downloaded the 10.10 installer, and burned it to a DVD.  When I go through the installer, I don't find an option to switch which disk Ubuntu gets installed on, as in 10.04.  Is this gone, and I need to use the long, complicated scripts that I am unable to use, as I don't have a working internet connection?

Right now, **all I want is to have a simple yes/no** about whether the drop-down menu for installing to a different drive is gone, **or instructions on finding it somewhere else**.  A link to alternate (easy) installation methods would be appreciated if the menu is gone.

Don't think anyone will find this useful, but here is my setup:

- Ubuntu 10.10 for PPC Live CD
- eMac
- Western Digital 160 GB Enhanced IDE Hard Drive (Model WD1600JB) connected by FireWire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you still have this option. When on "Allocate drive space" go to "Specify partitions manually".
[This](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2010/10/12/ubuntu-10-10-manual-disk-partitioning-guide/) can help.
<s>[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/installation-guide/index.html) is the official guide for Ubuntu 10.10.</s>
[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/installation-guide/index.html) is the official guide for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thank you for the help, that looks exactly like what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

For running Ubuntu/Linux off an external hard drive connected via USB the process is actually quite simple to do. Here are the steps, or rather, the steps I took.

*Please Note: The following steps were tested using Ubuntu Version 9.10, but has not been tested with the later versions. Use at your own risk & discretion.*

### What You Will Need

1. A Computer with Internet access.
2. A LiveCD or LiveUSB with Ubuntu.
3. An external Hard Drive with USB capability.

### What To Do

1. Open up your computer and remove the Hard Drive.
2. Plug in your external USB Hard Drive via the USB cable.
3. Stick in your LiveUSB or LiveCD and then boot up your PC.
4. Open up the boot menu, and choose to boot from the LiveCD/LiveUSB.
5. During the installation process you should your external hard drive listed, install Ubuntu to that.
6. Finish the installation process, turn off your PC, and put your other hard drive back into your computer.
7. Reboot your computer, go to the boot menu and select your external hard drive and attempt to boot from it. If it does congratulations, you now have an external hard drive with a full fledged Operating System on it.
8. Enjoy your external hard drive running Ubuntu/Linux!
   Please do let me know if this helps you! If not let me know about that too. :)

Comment: The problem (as I remember it, I am not currently even using the hard drive right now) was that I couldn't find the menu option for the external hard drive.  I knew how to do it in 10.04, but it changed in 11.  I appreciate your wanting to help with this, but the question was answered two months ago.